# Время жизни куки JS

Tags: javascript, cookie

Как задать время жизни куки 3 минуты

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
if(!expires) expires = new Date(2100,01,01);
if(!path) path = '/';
//var curCookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
var curCookie = name + "=" + value +
    "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() +
    "; path=" + path +
    ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
    ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
document.cookie = curCookie;}

setCookie('city', city, new Date(date.getMinutes()+3000), '/', "example.com");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function setCookie(name, value, time, path, domain, secure) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (time * 1000));

    document.cookie = name + '=' + value +
    '; path=' + path +
    '; expires=' + date.toUTCString() +
    '; domain=' + ((domain) ? domain : '') +
    '; secure=' + ((secure) ? secure : '');
}
```

```js
setCookie('city', 'Muhosransk', 180, '/', 'example.com');  // задать или обновить
setCookie('city', null, -1, '/'); // удалить
```

Comment: можете конкретно в моём коде исправить?

Comment: домен мне обязателен

Comment: @ChromeChrome, ответ устраивает?

Comment: Спасибо, как сделать так чтобы куки при открытии страницы сразу бы обновлялась

Comment: @ChromeChrome, задать время `-1` тому же `name`, а потом установить новые

Comment: А можете написать, как это будет в данном примерчике?

Comment: @ChromeChrome, Просто прописать функцию setCookie с параметрами. Время само обновится. Для удаления `setCookie('city', null, -1, '/');`

Comment: при использовании данного способа setCookie('city', null, -1, '/'); обновятся ли у человека закешированные данные

Comment: @ChromeChrome, удалится куки с ключём 'city'. При обновлении нужно снова задать `setCookie('city', 'Muhosransk', 180, '/', 'example.com');`

Comment: для полного понимания, у человека были куки двух недельной давности  с ключом 'city', при использовании сего кода они обновятся?setCookie('city', null, -1, '/');

Comment: @ChromeChrome, если куки были установлены, например, на две недели и тут он заходит спустя неделю, то куки у него обновятся и станут снова на две недели